# Question regarding the Smith-Waterman algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am running some string matching tests using the Smith-Waterman algorithm. I am currently using SimMetrics (the Java open source project) to run the tests.

Can anyone explain why when I compare 'Bloggs J.' to 'Bloggs' I get a similarity value of 1.0?

There obviously is a gap (e.g. 'o' and '.'), but it does not appear to be penalized.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this question about the algorithm itself (ie. you are positively sure that your implementation is error-free, but you don't understand why the algorithm outputs this particular result), or about your implementation (which you suspect is erratic and therefore gives wrong results)?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that the implementation is correct, but I think it might be. I wonder if anybody could explain what the expected result is, and why.

Comment: Try the applet on: http://baba.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi Tur1ng, this applet is fantastic! Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 5):

The [Smith-Waterman Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman) is a **local** alignment algorithm.  That means that it's designed to align **pieces** of strings that align well, as opposed to aligning whole strings.  The "gap" you speak of is not supposed to be penalized as a gap because it is considered to have occurred outside the aligned region.  No string with the length of 'Bloggs' could possibly align better to 'Bloggs J.' than 'Bloggs' does.  If you want a global alignment, you should use the [Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch) instead.

Comment: Correct.  See this blog post for an overview of Smith-Waterman and more details on how implementation differs from Needleman-Wunsch: http://www.etherealbits.com/2013/04/string-alignment-dynamic-programming-dna/.